# JavaScript output in Math program

Tags: javascript, output

```js
const shape = {
  radius: 10,
  diameter() {
    return this.radius * 2;
  },
  perimeter: () => 2 * Math.PI * this.radius
};

console.log(shape.diameter());
console.log(shape.perimeter());
```

I know the diameter is 20, but why perimeter shows NaN?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a scope issue - the radius variable is not available inside the perimeter method and so is undefined. Changing the function to a regular method resolves the issue.

```js
const shape = {
  radius: 10,
  diameter() {
    return this.radius * 2;
  },
  perimeter() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius
  }
};

console.log(shape.diameter()); //gives 20
console.log(shape.perimeter()); // gives 62.83185307179586
```

Comment: When used in an arrow function (`() => ...`), the scope of `this` is the same scope as where the function is defined. In this case, it is `window`.

Comment: Thanks @Soc - that means that in order to have access to the radius variable - it would need to be in the global scope and outside of the shape object.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you plan to use it, you may be better served with a `class`. In the example below, `this` in the arrow function refers to the `Circle` instance.

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  
  diameter() {
    return this.radius * 2;
  }
  
  perimeter = () => 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
}

const shape = new Circle(10);

console.log(shape.diameter());
console.log(shape.perimeter());
```

That said, if you are using a `class`, I prefer the way that `diameter` is defined over `perimeter` as an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

hello   perimeter as function not used arrow function(() =>)

> perimeter() {
>       return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius   }